# How can I mantain my position on the page on auto refresh after php function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I know that this is only possible with AJAX, but i've never worked with AJAX... On my website you can keep a list of the cards that you have from the game Magic, this is quite the list. You have to press a button to add a card, each card has this button and when you add it, It will add the card to your list then refresh and be at the top of the page again. How can i make it that it keeps it's position? So that the people who use this can easily keep adding cards to their collection.

I'm reposting this because I didn't get any working answers, I still want to thank the people tho tried to help me!

Inside of the red squares you can press add or remove : http://prntscr.com/5uq6ak

Function to add card :

```
//Add card to collection
function addCardToCollection($conn, $userID, $cardID){
//Checks if the cards is already added for this user
    $queryGetCard = 'SELECT user_id, card_id FROM collection WHERE user_id = '.$userID.' AND card_id = '.$cardID;
    $checkCollection = $conn->query($queryGetCard);
    if($checkCollection->fetch_assoc() > 0){return 'Deze kaart hebt u al.';}

//Adds card to the database
    $queryAddCard = 'INSERT INTO collection (user_id, card_id) VALUES ('.$userID.','.$cardID.')';
    if($conn->query($queryAddCard)){return 'Kaart toegevoed.';}
    else{return 'Kaart niet toegevoed.';}
}
```

The button and the card:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <b>Naam:</b> <a href="'.$baseURL.'card.php?multiverseid='.$value['multiverseid'].'&setName='.$result[0]['name'].'">'.$value['name'].'</a>
            <br><b>Beschrijving:</b> '.$value['text'].'
            <br><b>Flavor:</b> '.$value['flavor'].'
            <br><b>Artist:</b> '.$value['artist'].'
            <br>';
            if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {
                $cardsHTML.='<br><b>Deze kaart heb ik...
                <a href="' . $baseURL . 'set.php?id=' . $_GET['id'] . '&cardID=' . $value['id'] . '&collection=add">
                    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green"></div>
                </a> |
                <a href="' . $baseURL . 'set.php?id=' . $_GET['id'] . '&cardID=' . $value['id'] . '&collection=remove">
                    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red"></div>
                </a>
                </b>';
            }
         $cardsHTML.='</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <b>Type:</b> '.$value['type'].'
            <br><b>Mana kosten:</b> '.$value['manaCost'].'
            <br><b>CMC:</b> '.$value['cmc'].'
            <br><b>Power:</b> '.$value['power'].'
            <br><b>Toughness:</b> '.$value['toughness'].'
            <br><b>Zeldzaamheid:</b> '.$value['rarity'].'
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use a hash tag.

Comment: putvande, As i said this is indeed a duplicate. You can see in the question why...  and # doesn't work good with this big list

Comment: Why doesn't a hash work for such a long list? I see no other option than to use AJAX. And duplicates are usually not allowed.

Comment: That's what I want, AJAX. But the problem is i've never worked with it.

Comment: Suggest you start learning it. You can't expect somebody to write it for you. Just google AJAX and start from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extensive question. If you want to go for the AJAX approach, I can outline the steps for you, but you'll have to research them yourself:

1. Modify the PHP script you're calling to add the element to return a JSON format (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
2. On pressing the add button, create an AJAX request to the previously modified PHP script (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, ignore long texts, start with looking at the simple examples lower in the page)
3. Create a String variable in JavaScript with the HTML code you need inserted in the page
4. Get the JSON response from the PHP and add that into the previously created variable
5. Add that HTML code in the page with the jQuery append() function (see http://api.jquery.com/append/)

If you want the simpler approach, you must define some invisible anchors (`<a name="card3"></a>`) and then redirect to a URL that ends in #anchor-name, for example http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.php#card3